# Attempting to remove Apple's quarantine gives error "xattr: [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Tags: macos, permissions

I am attempting to remove quarantine from file permissions on osx; a similar starting point as [this](https://superuser.com/questions/526920/how-to-remove-quarantine-from-file-permissions-in-os-x) question.

However, when attempting the solution that worked there, I get:

```
$ xattr -d com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms myFile.pem
xattr: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'myFile.pem'
```

When I follow this up by applying sudo, I get:

```
$ sudo xattr -d com.apple.metadata myFile.pem 
xattr: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'myFile.pem'
```

Anyone know what's going on here? My file clearly exists and I am unsure of what to try next.

---

Edit

Attempting to delete explicitly specified attribute still gives:

```
sudo xattr -d com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms myFile.pem 
xattr: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'myFile.pem'
```

Answer (score 3):

In your second example you don't actually have a metadata attribute, i.e.

`sudo xattr -d com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms myFile.pem`

Try *listing* the extended attributes first before removing them, which you can do via:

`xattr -l myFile.pem`

Then you should know which ones to delete/change in order to get the file unquarantined.

For example, if I do this on a `.dmg` file I see:

`[~/Downloads]:;xattr -l yahoomessenger_3.0.2build235554.dmg 
com.apple.diskimages.fsck:
00000000  6A EE 43 E7 65 3C 02 09 FC CC FD EE C5 BA 6F 0C  |j.C.e<........o.|
00000010  F4 8B 4F 34                                      |..O4|
00000014
com.apple.diskimages.recentcksum: i:9292877 on 0B331FCB-4DC8-39B4-A12B-3A71BF73FD03 @ 1341527466 - CRC32:$BA65FD8D
com.apple.metadata:kMDItemDownloadedDate:
00000000  62 70 6C 69 73 74 30 30 A1 01 33 41 B8 ED A2 37  |bplist00..3A...7|
00000010  EA AD 71 08 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 01 00 00 00  |..q.............|
00000020  00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  00 00 00 00 13                                   |.....|
00000035
com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms:
00000000  62 70 6C 69 73 74 30 30 A1 01 5F 10 42 68 74 74  |bplist00.._.Bhtt|
00000010  70 3A 2F 2F 78 70 2E 79 69 6D 67 2E 63 6F 6D 2F  |p://xp.yimg.com/|
00000020  67 6A 2F 6D 73 67 72 2F 6D 61 63 2F 79 61 68 6F  |gj/msgr/mac/yaho|
00000030  6F 6D 65 73 73 65 6E 67 65 72 5F 33 2E 30 2E 32  |omessenger_3.0.2|
00000040  62 75 69 6C 64 32 33 35 35 35 34 2E 64 6D 67 08  |build235554.dmg.|
00000050  0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000060  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000070  4F                                               |O|
00000071
com.apple.quarantine: 0002;533d6ab7;Safari;79D54B00-8D85-4DF7-BB49-AA9C69B9B6E9`

So I see `com.apple.quarantine` and `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms`.  I think just removing the quarantine attribute should do it.

And I see the edits you did, try simply doing `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /explicit/path/to/myFile.pem` (i.e. pass along the exact filepath to the tool).  No need to do `sudo` here.

Comment: I updated my answer @user3224967 ; try using an explicit path to your `myFile.pem` file, too.  No need to do `sudo`.

Comment: Seems that on OS X 12.0.1, this doesn't work anymore (at least not without further modifications). 

```
xattr -l escript
com.apple.quarantine: 0081;61d5efb7;Chrome;6433DA40-BDB9-43E1-A407-14634506B156

xattr -d com.apple.quarantine escript
xattr: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'escript'
```

Comment: Ok my problem was that the files were not writable! So adding the write bit `chmod u+w <file>`, I was able to delete the extended attribute afterward.