# Cannot modify or delete file: xattr: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: macos, unix, permissions, zsh

I have tried multiple times to remove metadata and ACLs on a file (`prompt-info.js` below) so that I can modify or delete it. I have tried the answers in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92071/file-permissions-mode-ending-in-or) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41692997/attempting-to-remove-apples-quarantine-gives-error-xattr-errno-2-no-such-fi) (reproduced below), but nothing is working. I am running MacOS 12.1, and I do understand that ACLs have changed in recent versions of macOS. Nonetheless:

I had initially tried manually granting the file all permissions, and get this:

```
% ls -lah
total 136
drwxr-xr-x@ 15 adamg  staff   480B Jan 26 15:14 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 16 adamg  staff   512B Jan 20 11:39 ..
-rw-------@  1 adamg  staff   2.9K Jan 18 12:34 App.css
-rw-------@  1 adamg  staff    15K Jan 20 12:09 App.js
-rw-------   1 adamg  staff   5.5K Jan 25 16:53 prompt-info-Adam’s MacBook Pro (2).js
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 adamg  staff   5.4K Jan 20 11:47 prompt-info.js
```

In my terminal (iTerm2 running zsh) the filename `prompt-info.js` is also in red. I don't know if that helps at all.

When I try to view the metadata I get this:

```
% xattr -l prompt-info.js
xattr: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'prompt-info.js'
```

When I try to modify the metadata I receive the same error:

```
% xattr -c prompt-info.js
xattr: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'prompt-info.js'
```

When I try to remove the ACLs using `chmod -N prompt-info.js` it doesn't return an error, but then `ls -lah` still shows the exact same thing.

I also tried the command below, from the parent directory. It doesn't return an error, but I still receive the error about permission denied when I try `xattr`... afterwards:

```
(base) 14:24 Experiments/dialogue-keystrokes
chmod +a 'adamg allow read,write,delete,add_file,add_subdirectory,file_inherit,directory_inherit' src
```

Per @Gordan's comment below, when I run `ls -le0@`, it returns:

```
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 adamg  staff  -  5560 Jan 31 14:12 prompt-info.js
    com.apple.LaunchServices.OpenWith     118
    com.apple.fileutil.PlaceholderData    384
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS      16
    com.apple.metadata:com_apple_backup_excludeItem    61
    com.microsoft.OneDrive.RecallOnOpen     0
```

The full location of the directory is:

```
/Users/adamg/OneDrive - Northwestern University/Northwestern/Dissertation/Experiments/dialogue-keystrokes/src
```

Is there something I'm missing? I cannot resolve this issue.

Comment: What does `ls -leO@` show about the file? Also, what volume is it on?

Comment: Thanks, I just added that to my answer above. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Hmm, no ACL or file flags... maybe it's something to do with OneDrive (I don't have it set up to test with).

Comment: Yup, turns out to be a stupid OneDrive bug. I am done with them; it's such a buggy sync. If anyone stumbles upon this, you can find an example in the comments here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/onedrive-app-randomly-logs-out-and-loses-synced/28f4bc77-7f32-4b2a-b638-03e7bf712152. I was able to clear it by running `chmod -RN` on the parent directory.